# Meu vscode não executa o código no "output", mas sim no debug console

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, debug, configuração

Estou aprendendo a programar em JavaScript (Curso de Desenvolvimento WEB da Cod3r pelo Udemy) e estou tendo muitos problemas com o Visual Studio Code, que venho postergando por não conseguir resolver. Os seguintes problemas são:

1. Não conseguir executar o código no "output";
2. Não conseguir parar de rodar o código usando o Ctrl+Alt+M ou Ctrl+Alt+N.

1 -
Esse problema ocorre quando executo todo e qualquer código no VSCode, o curso onde uso de base, mostra que o instrutor executa o seu código e aparece no "output", entretanto no meu sempre apareceu no "Debug Console" quando aperto F5, que deveria ser o botão certo. Nunca mexi nada para consertar, se sim, falhei e desfiz. Porém uma gambiarra que consegui foi (olha o nível) baixar a extensão **Node.js Exec** https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=miramac.vscode-exec-node ainda por cima executando usando F8 porém não é o que eu quero, porquê não me parece certo. Como consertar?

2 -
Esse segundo problema ocorre quando eu fui aprender os comandos de `bind` no JavaScript, o seguinte exemplo foi:

```js
//Agora criando de uma outra forma usando diferentemente do ".bind(this)" 
function Pessoa(){
    this.idade = 0 
    
    const self = this //colocando uma variavel para this

    setInterval(function(){  
        //usando:

        self.idade++
        //no lugar de:
        // this.idade++

        console.log(this.idade)
    }.bind(this) , 1000)
}

new Pessoa
```

(Por favor não liguem para os comentários)

O instrutor do curso que com Ctrl+Alt+M parava de rodar o código, porém não acontece nem o Ctrl+Alt+N que é para continuar. Como proceder?

Comment: Desculpe Ian, o instrutor do Udemy não está respondendo suas perguntas? Eu estou fazendo Xamarin 2020 na Udemy e meu instrutor às vezes demora um pouco, mas sempre responde as perguntas.

Comment: Achei que por ser um problema no VSCode eu conseguiria resolver por aqui mais rápido, perguntei lá para ver o que vai rolar. Valeu mano <3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Geralmente o atalho F5 (VsCode) refere-se ao Step Into no processo de Debugg, deve ser este o motivo de seu programa aparecer no Debug Console. Para que apareça em OutPut, recomendo instalar a extensão Code Runner e acionar o atalho Crtl + Alt + N. Uma outra alternativa para finalizar o programa pode ser F1 + Stop Code Run.

Comment: Funcionou!!! Muito obrigado gente. Me questiono o porque que ele não funciona de forma natural sem precisar de extensões. Não é normal para mim um aplicativo não ser pronto para ser usado (risos). Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Que bom! Algumas linguagens para se programar no VsCode realmente necessitam de muitas extensões, é estranho, mas logo se acostuma. Espero ter ajudado de alguma forma.

Answer (score 0):

Usa a extensão "Node.js Exec". Você precisa baixar o node (na internet nodejs.org) daí instala a extensão, assim que você instalar a extensão (você precisa ter o node instalado pra ela funcionar), você vai no seu código JavaScript Puro (não tente usar ele com coisas nativas que apenas o browser pode renderizar, mas se for coisas como console.log, funções ou aplicações node ele vai funcionar) e aperta o botão f8, ele vai abrir uma aba e vai rodar o node. Se você quiser customizar (você vai querer) você pode ir na aba de instalação da extensão e ver alguns comandos e configurações pra deixar ele do jeito que você preferir.

Parece muito trabalho mas é bem rápido na verdade, segue os passos que dá certo. Ah... e o VSCode é apenas um editor de código super poderoso, por mais que seja cômodo pra nós ele não tem a obrigação nativa de substituir o browser do seu computador. Agradeça a nossa comunidade de modders que fazem essas extensões que facilitam nossa vida.